# pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()をすると使用メモリが増大する問題への対処

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, kaggle

KaggleのNotebook上で以下のようなpandas.DataFrameをnumpy.ndarrayに変換したいです。

```
>>> train.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 458913 entries, 0000099d6bd597052cdcda90ffabf56573fe9d7c79be5fbac11a8ed792feb62a to fffff1d38b785cef84adeace64f8f83db3a0c31e8d92eaba8b115f71cab04681
Columns: 918 entries, P_2_mean to D_68_<lambda_0>
dtypes: float64(891), int64(25), object(2)
memory usage: 3.1+ GB
```

上記コマンド実行時のKaggleのNotebookのRAMは最大16GBのうち6.6GB使用されています。

この状態で以下のコードを実行すると、KaggleのNotebookに`Your notebook tried to allocate more memory than is available. It has restarted.`とエラーが発生します。

```
>>> train_narray = train.to_numpy(copy=False)
```

[APIリファレンス](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)から`copy=False`を指定した場合もコピーが作成される場合もあるということは分かったのですが、RAM使用量が2.4倍以上に膨れ上がるのは納得いきません。

> Note that copy=False does not ensure that to_numpy() is no-copy.

少ないRAMでpandas.DataFrameをnampy.ndarrayに変換する方法ありましたら教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.to_numpy()`を実行したときにコピーが作成されないのは、元のデータフレームの全ての列が同じNumPyデータ型になっている場合だけです。

元のデータフレームは列によってデータ型が異なっています（`float64(891), int64(25), object(2)`）。この場合は、データフレームの各列がそれぞれ別のNumPy配列になっています。
ここで`DataFrame.to_numpy()`を実行すると、全ての列が1つのNumPy配列に統合されるるため、必ずデータ型を変換したコピーが作成されます（しかも質問の状況では、おそらく`train_narray`は高価なオブジェクトデータ型になります）。

解決策としては、列ごとに`Series.to_numpy()`を実行することです。
あるいはデータ型が同じものに限って実行すれば（例えば`train.select_dtypes("int").to_numpy()`のように）、コピーが作成されたとしてもオブジェクトデータ型にキャストされることはないでしょう。

また`.to_records()`メソッドで、NumPyのレコード配列という列ごとに異なるデータ型を持てる配列に変換できます（コピーが作られます）が、私はあまり使ったことがないので、メモリにどのような影響があるのかはわかりません。

Comment: > DataFrame.to_numpy()を実行したときにコピーが作成されないのは、元のデータフレームの全ての列が同じNumPyデータ型になっている場合だけです。

初耳でした。

object型のデータをint64にラベルエンコードし、データ型ごとに`to_numpy()`を実行したところ無事メモリに乗りました。

ご回答ありがとうございました。